# Dynamic Persistent volume in Kubernetes

Tags: persistence, kubernetes, glusterfs

I have a kubernetes cluster on 1.4.6 and trying to configure the dynamic persistence volume based on glusterfs. I have created the glusterfs cluster and have the volume created as well.

gluster volume info

```
Volume Name: volume1
Type: Replicate
Volume ID: xxxxxxxxx
Status: Started
Number of Bricks: 1 x 2 = 2
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: <host-1>:/gluster-storage
Brick2: <host-2>:/gluster-storage
Options Reconfigured:
performance.readdir-ahead: on
```

From the kubernetes side, a storageclass is created with the storageclass.beta.kubernetes.io/is-default-class as "true" and the provisioner is set as kubernetes.io/glusterfs. With this configuration, when the PVC is created, its pending and never gets bound. While checking the PV, there is no PV created using the gluster-storage driver mentioned in the storageclass.

- Is the dynamic provisioning using glusterFs is available for 1.4.6
- Is there any specific configuration needs to be enabled when kube controller
  is started.

Following are the yml files for reference.

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: slow
  annotations:
    storageclass.beta.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
provisioner: kubernetes.io/glusterfs
parameters:
  endpoint: "glusterfs-cluster"
  resturl: "<Host IP for Gluster>"
  restauthenabled: "false"
  restuser: ""
  restuserkey: ""

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
 name: pvc-claim
 annotations:
   volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: default
spec:
 accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
 resources:
   requests:
     storage: 1Gi
```

Has anybody done the dynamic provisioning using the glusterfs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the parameter `volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class` value `slow` in `PersistentVolumeClaim` which you have set in  `StorageClass`.